# Real Life example of Polymorphism from Class Room

Tags: oop, polymorphism

Once my teacher asked me to give example of `polymorphism` from class room.
I told him that you are best example of polymorphism. As in college you are a teacher and in home you are husband or father. So your are one method but in different states you are behaving accordingly. And also you are extending human so you can be treated polymorphically as human.

(Considering in mind definition of polymorphism: `Acquiring more than one form`)

Can it be consider as good example of `polymorphism` ?

Thanks.

Comment: Depends on your teacher's face :P well it is an example. good or bad is non-deterministic value :P

Comment: It might be ;-). if you want to satisfy with your answer, read the real time example in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173152.aspx. They gave real time example using drawing application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, you give different behaviours for different states.

In OOP this is expressed through interfaces.

So, it would be modelled something like this:

```
class Human
{ 
    Date Birthdate;
}

interface ITeacher
{
    void Teach();
}

interface IHusband
{
    void Pray();
}

interface IFather
{
    void Love();    // methods in IFather and IHusband can be interchanged
}

class Person extends Human implements ITeacher, IHusband, IFather
{
   // implementations inserted here
}
```

Now you can use those behaviours and the fact that he is a human in different cases.

Like:

```
 Human yourTeacher = new Human("1970/05/01");

 Class class = new Class();
 class.Teachers.Add(yourTeacher); // expecting that it is a collection of ITeachers.

 Pub pub = new Pub();
 pub.DrunkPeople.Add(yourTeacher); // accepting only humans older than 21 here
```

So, polymorphism is about **ONE** object that behaves different in different cases... and inheritance.